# Bash Getting Access To Scripts In Subfolders Only While In Certain Directory

Tags: bash, scripting, code-snippets

To elaborate,

Project Structure

```
current-working-directory
  -- scripts [d]
    -- script1 [d]
      -- script1 [f]
    -- script2 [d]
      -- script2 [f]
  -- README [f]
  -- executable [f]
```

**Main Idea**: I want to be able to run say *function1* located in **script1** as long as
I am in *current-working-directory* or any subfolders.

I had multiple goes at this:

**IDEA#1** .bashrc

```sh
function cd {
    builtin cd $@
    local dir
    if [ -d "bpm_modules" ]; then
      for dir in $(ls bpm_modules);do
        . "$PWD/bpm_modules/$dir/$dir"
      done
    fi
  }
```

wrapper around cd command

Caveat: since I source the files, once i leave the directory I still have access.

---

**IDEA#2** .bashrc

```sh
function require {
    # You Have Gone Too Far
    [ "$1" == "$HOME" ] && return 1
    
    # Assign Parameters Accordingly
    [ $# -eq 1 ] && local CWD="$PWD" && local QUERY="$1"
    [ $# -eq 2 ] && local CWD="$1" && local QUERY="$2"
    local FOUND_MODULE=1

    # Error Handling
    function trapper {
        local BOO=$1
        local QUERY=$2
        NOT_FOUND="$(tput setaf 1)[DEPENDENCY]: $(tput sgr0)missing '$QUERY'"
        
        [[ $BOO -eq 1 ]] && echo "$NOT_FOUND"
    }
    
    # If In BCS Initialized Project
    if [ -d "$CWD/.bpm" ]; then
        
        # Check For Module
        for DIR in $( ls $CWD/bpm_modules); do
            [ "$DIR" == "$QUERY" ] && FOUND_MODULE=0 && source $CWD/bpm_modules/$DIR/$DIR
        done
        trap "trapper $FOUND_MODULE $QUERY" $?
    # Else Go Up A Directory Recursively
    else
        CWD_UP1=$(cd $CWD && cd .. && pwd)
        require $CWD_UP1 $QUERY
    fi

}
```

require would be used inside of say the `executable` from the project-directory graph above, followed by the script/folder name like so `require script1`, sourcing the file and allowing me to use functions inside `executable`

---

[Repo @ Github](https://github.com/rbrtbrnschn/bash-package-manager)

[Package-Library](https://annalee.rbrtbrnschn.dev)

PS: I got 2 weeks of bash experience so..., id appreciate any recommandations or harsh truths.

PS1: '*bash puns amirite*',this is used for a **bash-package-manager** im currently working on.

Comment: If you use the absolute path you will be able to access from any dir `source  /path/to/modules/bpm_modules/$dir/$dir"

Comment: @Noris : As you say correctly, the function stays defined if you move out of your current directory. You could do a `unset -f functionname`, before you leave the directory, but this means that you need to know the names of all functions you want to forget. Does it **have** to be functions? If you would use bash scripts instead, and only access them using a relative path, you automtically can only access the "right" ones.

Comment: @user1934428 : as far as im concerned as of right now, function would be the way to go.
i wouldnt want the scripts to run on require - (similar to nodejs or npm if u will), is what id be going for, as for that i woudnt ever know all function names i want to 'forget'

Comment: Then it gets tough. You could, before sourcing the file(s) with the new functions, parse the output from `typeset -f`, to find which functions are defined right now. After sourcing the fi1les, you parse again the list of functions. From this, you know which functions have been added, and you can do the respective `unset` when going back.

Comment: @user1934428 : that is splendid, i really havent looked into set,unset and the such. what a shame. Thank you, ill get back to you, once i tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say I am running a script called `my_script.sh`. If I want to implement your require function, that will source the script given in argument if that this script is located in a directory `$my_dir`, and crash otherwise, you can do:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

require() {
    if realpath --relative-to="$my_dir" "$1" | fgrep ../; then
        echo Script "$1" is not located in directory "$my_dir", exiting. >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    source $1
}
```

Please note that this would fail if a directory in the path returned by `realpath` ends with `..`. I think this is a reasonable limitation, but just so you know, in order to fix that, you could replace `fgrep ../` by `grep '\(^\.\./\)\|/\.\./'`.

Comment: As far I understand the requirements, this does not approach the problem. The OP is not so much interested in finding the scripts to source, he wants to "undo" the function definitions in those scripts, when he is leaving the directory.